# Is it possible to override "Change Owner" button from listview items menu?

Tags: list-view, button, button-overrides, search-layout, owner

As the title says: Is it possible to override "Change Owner" button from listview items menu? If so, how can be done?

[image]

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

It is a kind of limitation in Salesforce. Check out this Idea:- [Allow [Change] owner button to be overriden](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpmu)

> It says it would be nice to be able to override the "Change" owner
>   button on all records. S-Controls/URL hacks etc. could maybe then be
>   employed to modify/set checkboxes that appear on the "Change" dialogue
>   menus to be defaulted a certain way/modified etc...